# CCSID 273 encoding not recognised by VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, encoding, localization, ibm-midrange

I am using VS Code to connect to an IBM i server. The encoding associated with my user profile in the server is CCSID 273, which is not included in the VS Code list, so I'm not able to open files using this encoding, and some characters are misunderstood by the VS Code editor.

I am connecting to the IBM i server using the Code for IBM i VS Code extension. I've tried to adjust the extension settings in different ways so the CCSID is recognised, but I never get the correct result.

I've also tried to open the files in VS Code using different encodings but none of the included in the VS Code list are able to recognise correctly the complete set of characters.

Is there any way to add the CCSID 273 encoding to VS Code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Post an issue to the project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/halcyon-tech/vscode-ibmi/issues). One of the maintainers should be able to help you either adjust your configuration so that it works correctly, or work on a fix to the extension. It's actively developed and maintained, and the main author is very responsive, so you will definitely get results if you do this.